# Concept Question: Variable buffer analysis size depending on file type?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcpy

Enlighten a Python novice? I am trying to execute a large amount of buffer analyses on a group of files. I'm trying to make it so the polyline and multipoint files are selected for the buffer. So far I have the files prepped and described so I know which ones to select, but any insight on how I can tell python to only grab the polylines and multipoints?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
path = "Insert file folder path names here"
arcpy.env.workspace = z = path
```

```
allfc = []
for a,b,c in arcpy.da.Walk(x):
    for d in c:
        allfc.append(a+'/'+d)
print allfc
```

```
for fc in allfc:
    d = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    print "\n" + "\n" 
    print d.basename
    print d.shapeType
    print "\n"
```

```
for fc in allfic:
    if d.shapeType == "Polyline":
         d = "300 Meters"
    else d.shapeType == "Multipoint":
         d = "500 Meters"
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, fc+"_BUF", d, "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL")
```

It's the last part that's giving me grief and I know I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few different ways that you could handle how the logic ends up flowing through this process, and it may be useful to experiment to see if you can find additional ways to solve it. However, here are my suggestions for where your code is going wrong and how you can improve it.

---

1. Generally, more descriptive variable names are better. Sure, `dist` or `desc` take longer to type than `d`, but you are using `d` for three unique things that I can see in your script, and that is causing some of the problem in that last `for` loop.
2. In the last loop, you are looping through `allfic` instead of `allfc` but that's just a typo. But even if you fixed that...
3. You are looping through `for fc in allfc` twice. This means that you loop through `allfc` all the way, and come out of it with `d` being the `Describe` object of the last feature class in the loop. Let's say it's a polyline. You then loop through `allfc` again from the beginning, and `d.shapeType == "Polyline"` is true (even if first feature class in the loop is actually a polygon). So the loop dutifully sets `d` to `300 Meters` and then executes the Buffer operation. The loop then goes to the second feature class, but `d` is now a string (`300 Meters`) instead of a Describe object, and so will never work properly for the rest of the feature classes in your list.
4. You should use `elif` ("else if") instead of `else` when checking whether it's a Multipoint. Realistically, you can just use `if`, though -- if you're in `else` territory you just want the feature class to be skipped over, so you can leave that out.
5. Finally: every `fc` in `allfc` is going to be sent through the `Buffer` tool. (Only Polylines and Multipoints get a buffer distance set, but every feature class will *attempt* that operation regardless. And if it's a Polygon instead of a Polyline, it will simply use the distance from the last time through the loop!) So you need to put that operation within a conditional as well.

---

```py
for fc in allfc:
    # describe the feature class
    d = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    print "\n" + "\n" 
    print d.basename
    print d.shapeType
    print "\n"

    # determine what buffer distance should be
    if d.shapeType == "Polyline":
         dist = "300 Meters"
    if d.shapeType == "Multipoint":
         dist = "500 Meters"

    # buffer the feature class only if it is the correct shapeType
    if d.shapeType == "Polyline" or d.shapeType == "Multipoint":
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, fc+"_BUF", dist, "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL")
```